# Sort table and get row position Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table name test_results where with columns - id, user_id, marks, accuracy.

Now I need to rank them based on mark and accuracy, so I do like this-

```
$results= TestResult::orderBy('mark', 'desc')->orderBy('accuracy', 'desc')->get();
```

So, here i can easily find the rank-

```
foreach($results as $index => $result)
    <li>{{$result->user->name}} (Rank - {{$index + 1}}) </li>
```

But how can I find the rank without fetching all the recods. For ex

```
$result = TestResult::findOrFail($id);
```

How can I find the rank of this result.

The ranking factor will be same as above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a LEFT JOIN with the same table in a raw query and count all rows which are ordered before the one you select:

```
$result = ModelName::hydrateRaw("
    select t1.*, count(t2.id) + 1 as rank
    from table_name t1
    left join table_name t2
      on t2.mark > t1.mark
      or t2.mark = t1.mark and t2.accuracy > t1.accuracy
    where t1.id = ?
    group by t1.id
", [$id])->first();
```

Then you can access the rank just with `$result->rank`.

Note that this doesn't handle ties (when `t2.mark = t1.mark` and `t2.accuracy = t1.accuracy`). So if ties are possible you should sort them by a unique key (primary key should be fine). Then the ON clause would be

```
      on t2.mark > t1.mark
      or t2.mark = t1.mark and t2.accuracy > t1.accuracy
      or t2.mark = t1.mark and t2.accuracy = t1.accuracy and t2.id > t1.id
```

But you should also adjust your original query to:

```
$results = TestResult::orderBy('mark', 'desc')
                     ->orderBy('accuracy', 'desc')
                     ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                     ->get();
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/WMUJ37627

Also note that you can compare tuples in MySQL, and your ON clause could also be

```
on (t2.mark, t2.accuracy, t2.id) > (t1.mark, t1.accuracy, t1.id)
```

But MySQL might not be able to optimize it for an index use.

#### Update

In version 5.4 `hydrateRaw()` has been renamed to `fromQuery()`.

Comment: I'm getting an error - Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hydrateRaw does not exist. I' working on laravel 5.6. Tried with raw, but the results are not as required..

Comment: @SunnyKumar They renamed it to `fromQuery()` ([Upgrading To 5.4.0 From 5.3](https://docs.golaravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade/))

Comment: The results are not as expected. Right now in the table there are three entries. (id, live_test_id, user_id, mark, accuracy)- (1, 1, 1, 1, 100), (2,1,2,5,33), (3,1,3,12,100). I am trying to find rank of id 1. It shoud be 3, but I'm getting 2.

Comment: @SunnyKumar Sorry - I fixed several errors and added a demo now.